# Acumatica - computing field default value

Tags: field, default, acumatica

In Acumatica I want to compute a "Quote Expires" date on the Sales Order Entry form based on the date a new order of type "QT" is created.  This date would be computed by adding a default "Default Quote Expiry Days" as set up in the Sales Order Preferences.  For example if the default expiry days = 45 (setup) and the order is created on April 1, 2015 then the default date for "Quote Expires" on the Sales Order Entry form would be May 16, 2015 (April 1, 2015 plus 45 days).  The expiry date may be overridden by the user.

Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected virtual void SOOrder_UsrExpiredDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
    {
        SOOrder row = e.Row as SOOrder;
        if (row.OrderDate.HasValue)
        {
            e.NewValue = row.OrderDate.Value.AddDays(45);
        }
    }
```

For example I added custom field to SOOrder called UsrExpiredDate, feel free to replace number 45 with any kind of setup.